# Data from combobox to be viewed on datagridview

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, datagridview, combobox

```
Dim cnn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand

Private Sub loadData()
    If Not cnn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        cnn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.Oledb.12.0; Data Source=" & Application.StartupPath & "\LibrarySystem.accdb"
        'open connection
        cnn.Open()
    End If

    Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT StatusID, StatusDesc FROM BookStatus", cnn)
    Dim dt As New DataTable

    'fill data to datatable
    da.Fill(dt)
    'show data in data table into combobox
    Me.cmbBookStatus.DataSource = dt
    Me.cmbBookStatus.DisplayMember = "StatusDesc"
    Me.cmbBookStatus.ValueMember = "StatusID"

    'close connection
    cnn.Close()

End Sub
```

I want to show the data from the combobox on datagridview. Above are the codes I used. I've made a table in microsoft access for the bookstatus. But the data still didn't show up at the combobox. Can someone help meeee.

I put the codes for viewing the combobox data on datagridview under the save button.

```
Private Sub btnSave_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
    Dim cnn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection

    If Not cnn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        cnn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.Oledb.12.0; Data Source=" & Application.StartupPath & "\LibrarySystem.accdb"
        cnn.Open()
    End If

    If (txtBookID.Text = "" And txtBookTitle.Text = "" And txtPub.Text = "" And txtAuthor.Text = "" And cmbBookStatus.SelectedValue = "") Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please insert all field!", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    Else
        Dim msgbox As DialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure to save this record?", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question)

        If msgbox = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes Then
            'add new data
            Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
            cmd.Connection = cnn
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Book(BookID, Title, Publisher, Author, StatusID) " & _
            " VALUES('" & txtBookID.Text & "','" & txtBookTitle.Text & "','" & txtPub.Text & "','" & txtAuthor.Text & "','" & cmbBookStatus.SelectedValue & "')"

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

            MessageBox.Show("Data has been recorded", "Add New Record", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
            txtBookID.Clear()
            txtBookTitle.Clear()
            txtPub.Clear()
            txtAuthor.Clear()

        End If

        'refresh data          
        'Me.loadData()

        Dim db As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Book", cnn)
        Dim dt As New DataTable

        'fill data to datatable
        db.Fill(dt)
        'show data in data table into datagridview
        Me.dgvAddBook.DataSource = dt

        Dim column As DataGridViewColumn = dgvAddBook.Columns(1)
        column.Width = 269
    End If

    'close connection
    cnn.Close()

End Sub
```

Comment: Where in the code you tried to show `ComboBox` data in the `DataGridView`

Comment: I put the codes under the save button. Wait I'll edit my post. @Fabio

Comment: Sorry, I am still little bid confuse. Is problem that `ComboBox` is empty after `.DataSource` set. Or problem is that `ComboBox.SelectedValue` not saved in the Access datatable and doesn't displayed in the `DataGrdiView`

Comment: The problem now is the combobox is still empty even after .DataSource set. @Fabio

Comment: Check if data exists in the database table `BookStatus`